# Error in export gridview to excel

Tags: asp.net

I was tring to export gridview to excel.For that I wrote the code in content page.But I got the error.When I writting attribute[runat]="server";So I searched on the net I wrote like this.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) 
{ /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time. */ 
}
```

.But I remove all the code from my page.But When I am running the page it get display on the login page.I want to remove that sentence which is coming at run time.

Comment: I added code for export gridview in that I used above method,after some time I remove all code.Even that method also.But when I am running my login page the above function get written on the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "add griview to excel sheet"?

Comment: I was tring to export gridview to excel

Comment: Ok. What error you got? And what code you used to export the gridview to excel?

Comment: Now I remove all the code I don't to want export.I used the normal code which uses streamWriter,HtmlTextwriter class.That code work fine when I am doing in normal page.But when Writing in content page,it throws error saying only A page can have only one server-side Form tag.I think because of master page.So I searched on the net for error.forum detail says to use above meyhod.So add the VerifyRenderingInServerForm() in my form.But I remove all code and that method still that method get printed in my login page not the other page.My login page is a simple aspx page not a content page.

Comment: If you get this error "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" just make sure that you only have one form tag both in the masterpage and in the content page. Delete one of the forms that you don't use and it should run.

Comment: There is no form tag in content page.Now I am not looking in export grid.just tell me what should I do to not get display that method's code on my login page

Comment: Check for form pages in masterpage also. What do you mean by "what should I do to not get display that method's code on my login page"?

Comment: The above method get printed on my login page.There is no response.write

Comment: You need to give us a code of the login's page aspx and codebehind sample so we know where it prints it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one master page and remaining content page.The login page is not content page, is a simple aspx page.In my master page there is form tag.In a One of my content page,I added code for export to gridview.

```
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
 frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
```

So got the error.I searched on net for the error ,ppl was saying to use the method ,so I wrote that method.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) 
{ /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time. */ 
}
```

But problem was when I was running my project the code get display on my login page not remaing content page.So I removed all code and even that override method, still code get printed on my login page.I looked into login page for finding out that method get defined there.But there is no such method in login page.What should I do?How to remove that.